# Azure eventhub access in Azure Databricks

Tags: azure-databricks

I am trying to run following code in Azure databricks.

The library `azure_eventhubs_spark_2_12_2_3_17.jar` is registered on data bricks.
Databricks runtime version is `7.2 (includes Apache Spark 3.0.0, Scala 2.12)`

The code is part of Microsoft learn structured streaming module.
The code block that gives issue is below followed by the error message it gives. The code is part of Microsoft lean itself so there is no custom code that I have written.

```
%python

ehWriteConf = {
  'eventhubs.connectionString' : connection_string
}

checkpointPath = userhome + "/event-hub/write-checkpoint"
dbutils.fs.rm(checkpointPath,True)

(activityStreamDF
  .writeStream
  .format("eventhubs")
  .options(**ehWriteConf)
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointPath)
  .start())
```

This gives  error:

```
Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class 
org.apache.spark.eventhubs.package$
Py4JJavaError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3909542231316002> in <module>
      9   .writeStream
     10   .format("eventhubs")
---> 11   .options(**ehWriteConf)
     12   .start())

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/streaming.py in start(self, 
path, format, outputMode, partitionBy, queryName, **options)
   1223             self.queryName(queryName)
   1224         if path is None:
-> 1225             return self._sq(self._jwrite.start())
   1226         else:
   1227             return self._sq(self._jwrite.start(path))

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9- 
src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1304         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, 
self.name)
   1306 
   1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    125     def deco(*a, **kw):
    126         try:
--> 127             return f(*a, **kw)
    128         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    129             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in 
get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1} 
{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o785.start.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class 
org.apache.spark.eventhubs.package$
    at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSourceProvider.createSink(EventHubsSourceProvider.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSink(DataSource.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.createV1Sink(DataStreamWriter.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:386)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I also ran the newer versions of the databricks cluster and the eventhub library.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/PySpark/structured-streaming-pyspark.md#event-hubs-configuration), since eventhub library version 2.11:2.3.15 encryption is required for the connect string. That is why the current code in the notebook does not work. And it seems that in the new databricks cluster the newer library for eventhub is already installed.

I resolved the above issue by:

- creating a databricks cluster with runtime version: `6.4 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scale 2.11)`
- installed the library of of version: `com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11:2.3.7`

As recommended by

- [MS learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/process-streaming-data-azure-databricks-structured-streaming/3-perform-stream-processing-using)
- the notebook: `10-Structured-Streaming - 3.Streaming-With-Event-Hubs-Demo`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to Creating an EventHubs Sink for Streaming Queries:

```
# Set up the Event Hub config dictionary with default settings
writeConnectionString = "YOUR.EVENTHUB.NAME"
ehWriteConf = {
  'eventhubs.connectionString' : writeConnectionString
}

# Write body data from a DataFrame to EventHubs. Events are distributed across partitions using round-robin model.
ds = df \
  .select("body") \
  .writeStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehWriteConf) \
  .option("checkpointLocation", "///output.txt") \
  .start()

# Write body data from a DataFrame to EventHubs with a partitionKey
ds = df \
  .selectExpr("partitionKey", "body") \
  .writeStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehWriteConf) \
  .option("checkpointLocation", "///output.txt") \
  .start()
```

**Reference:** [Structured Streaming + Event Hubs Integration Guide for PySpark](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/PySpark/structured-streaming-pyspark.md)